# Fold expression has empty expansion

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have some very heavily templated code, where I need to pass configuration flags encoded as `unsigned` via a template.

```cpp
template<unsigned T>
struct MemoryTraits
{
    // Do something with T...
};
```

There are some predefined flags, that I'm supposed to bit-or, and pass to the struct above, then it will be passed further to other templated functions and classes.

```cpp
SomeTemplatedContainer</*other parameters */, MemoryTraits<Trait1 | Trait2>> myContainer{};
```

I was trying to create a variadic template function, that would take any number of flags, and alias the `MemoryTraits`, depending on template parameters.

```cpp
template<unsigned ...Traits>
void foo() {
    using MyMemoryTraits = MemoryTraits<(Traits | ...)>;
    SomeTemplatedContainer</*other parameters */, MyMemoryTraits> myContainer{}   
}
```

I tried to implement it using c++17 fold expressions, and everything works when I invoke `foo` with one or more arguments, but when calling it without any, I get the following compile time error.

> error: expected expression
>
> foo(); -> fold expression has empty expansion

From what I understand, it's because an empty fold expression with `operator |` doesn't have a default value, is there any way I can provide a default value to it? So far I came up with the following helper lambda.

```cpp
constexpr auto TraitsHelper = [](){
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Traits) == 0){
            return 0;
        } else if constexpr(sizeof...(Traits) == 1){
            constexpr std::array TRAITS{Traits...};
            return TRAITS[0];
        } else {
            return (Traits | ...);
        }
    };
```

It works, at least for now, but is there some better way to fix this issue?

Comment: what about `(Traits | ... | 0u)` ? Or `(0u | ... | Traits)`, if you prefer.

Comment: Both of them work, I completly forgot that the expansion need to be in the middle